# When are Backticks ' ' used compared to Double Quotes " "?

Tags: r, tibble

What I know so far ...

1) Backticks are used when creating tibbles with non-syntactic variable/column names that contain numbers, spaces, or other symbols (because normally you can only name columns with letters right?)

```
 tb <- tibble( 
               ': ) ' = "smile, ' ' = "space", 
               '2000' = "number", "double_quotes" = "normal_text")
```

However, when I use double quotes here the tibble still forms with the nonsyntactic symbols/numbers.

2) Double quotes are used to subset column names when using double brackets.

```
  tb[["double_quotes"]]
```

And here, when I use single quotes to subset, it still works as well.

3) When subsetting using $, to select for nonsyntactic names, I must use single quotes, but here again, if I subset using double quotes, it works as well

Again, `tb$": )"` works just as well as `tb$': )'`

So are they effectively interchangeable?

---

Interestingly, when I plot a graph

```
annoying <- tibble(
  `1` = 1:10,
  `2` = `1` * 2 + rnorm(length(`1`))
)

ggplot(annoying, aes(x = `1`, y = `2`)) +
  geom_point()
```

Single quotes **must** be used when referring to the nonsyntactic variables because otherwise, it looks like ggplot treats X and Y as single points of 1 and 2 respectively. Are there any other cases like this?

Comment: *single* quotes ' and *double* quotes " are completely interchangeable. *backticks* (or back-single-quotes) are different.

Comment: For `tibble` or `data.frame` or plainly on the console, backticks (`\``, not `'`) are *required* on variable names when they are not normally legal (start with letter, and contains letter, number, dot, or underscore, [ref](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/make.names.html)). While both `x` and `\`x\`` are fine, they both work; if a frame column is named `1` or `a b` (space), then one must use backticks to reference them, as in `\`1\`` and `\`a b\``.

Answer (score 5):

It's important to distinguish between single quotes (') and backticks (or "back-single-quotes") (`).

Most of what you want to know is in `?Quotes`:

> Single (') and double (") quotes delimit character constants.  They can be
>        used interchangeably but double quotes are preferred (and
>        character constants are printed using double quotes), so single
>        quotes are normally only used to delimit character constants
>        containing double quotes.
>
> Almost always, other [i.e., non-syntactically valid] names can be used
>        provided they are quoted.  The preferred quote is the backtick
>        (‘`’) ... under many
>        circumstances single or double quotes can be used (as a character
>        constant will often be converted to a name).  One place where
>        backticks may be essential is to delimit variable names in
>        formulae: see ‘formula’.

For example, if you want to define a variable name containing a space, you need back-ticks:

```
`a b` <- 1
```

Double quotes also work here (to my surprise!)

```
"a b" <- 1
```

but if you want to use the resulting variable in an expression you'll need to use back-ticks. `"a b" + 1` gives an error (" non-numeric argument to binary operator") but `` `a b`+1 `` works.

As @r2evans points out, the same rules apply in tidyverse expressions. You can use double- or single-quotes (if you want) to define new variables: `mtcars %>% mutate("my stuff"=4)`, but if you want to subsequently use that variable (or any other non-syntactic variable) in an expression, you have to backtick-protect it: `` mtcars %>% mutate("my stuff"=4, new=`my stuff` + 5) ``.

It's probably best practice/least confusing to just use backticks for all non-syntactic variable reference and single quotes for character constants.